# How to fix css3 shadow with pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

The shadow created with `:before` and `:after` goes under the parent `div`. How can I fix it? The shadow of the parent `div` works fine.

[image]

**CSS:**

```
article {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    background: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 20em auto;
}


article:before, article:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width:300px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);   
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);    
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);   
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

article:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>this div has also a nice shadow effect (works), but created with another div by z-index:-1;
                        <article>
                            <p>this will have a nice shadow effect(doesnt work)</p>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    ...
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or a link to a live page so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS fiddle of the posted code, cleaned up a bit.](http://jsfiddle.net/dybFr/3/)

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors allow you to add *content* to the text node of the element. **You cannot add additional elements or nodes into the DOM using these pseudo-selectors.**

I'm not sure what content you're wanting to style since you're appending a blank string, but right now you're trying to add a **box shadow** to **text**.

Additionally, you have completely garbled indention in your CSS, and you have some rogue HTML tags. You should spend 12 seconds looking at the code you posted up for us to spend time reading in order to deduce and help with your misunderstanding; if you respect our time by spending time on *your* question, you would get better help.

Comment: sorry. i added an image how it should look like and how it doesnt

Comment: @coreyward... your fiddle doesn't work for me in Chrome, meaning, there are no shadows anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/NAEmW/2/ .
Tested OK in both FF and Chrome, of course IE<=8 is hopeless.

One thing that can kill this is a CSS reset, so be careful about what gets zeroed-out.